# Selenium xpath for image recognition

Tags: html, xpath, selenium-webdriver

The html code looks some thing like the below

```
<image x="128" y="6" width="16" height="16" href="ide/editor/plugin/analytics/images/CollapseAll.png"/>
```

When I searched for the answer most of them were for `img` tag and not for "image"
further below are  the options what i have tried and didn't work

```
//image[contains(.,'CollapseAll')]
//img[contains(.,'CollapseAll')]
//img[@href = 'ide/editor/plugin/analytics/images/CollapseAll.png']
//image[@href = 'ide/editor/plugin/analytics/images/CollapseAll.png']
```

Wham i doing wrong?

Regards,
Vinoth

Comment: What is the error message you are getting?

Comment: Your last xpath or using contains like "//image[contains(@href,'CollapseAll')]" should work.

Comment: use absolute Xpath instead of relative . sometimes it will works. i have faced same issue but using absolute xpath it works for me. i hope it works for you also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use //*[@href='ide/editor/plugin/analytics/images/CollapseAll.png'] for this.